# Easiest way to convert HEIC to JPEG or PNG

Tags: iphone, photos, image-formats

I just got an unwanted surprise this morning when downloading some photos from my [iCloud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICloud): the photos are in [HEIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Efficiency_Image_File_Format) format.

This appears to be some format that Apple is pushing on me, but at this point it's an obstacle. Moreover, I never asked for my photo downloads to land as HEIC format. I don't want that. **I** ***never*** **want my photos in HEIC format; I want them in JPEG or PNG**. Maybe I fat-fingered some setting? Maybe it's a consequence of the latest iOS? This also happened a couple of years ago and I don't remember what I did to fix it.

What's the easiest way to make this not happen? Ideally I would like to just change a setting on my phone or possibly iCloud/photos, but if I have to, I will look into a converter that isn't a hassle to use (for example, [GIMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIMP) is hard *no*; maybe [ImageMagick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ImageMagick) if there's only one or two arguments).

For what it’s worth, I am on Windows 10/11.

Comment: Imagimagick is really two args: `convert file.heic file.jpg`.

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207022

Comment: Your preference is clear.  But FYI: The path of least resistance may be to make your Windows computer compatible with High-Efficiency Image Format.  It's about twice as space-efficient as JPEG at a given quality level.  Plenty of free tools, like https://apps.microsoft.com/detail/9MXHSBJRS7SH?hl=en-us&gl=US available.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to copy HEIC files from iPhone (ios 11.1) to Windows PC](https://superuser.com/questions/1279679/how-to-copy-heic-files-from-iphone-ios-11-1-to-windows-pc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On iCloud.com, select the circle with three dots in it and then "More download options". A pop-up window will appear and you'll need to select "Most compatible" to ensure you don't get HEVC.

If you want to convert the HEVC files you already have on your computer, then something like ImageMagick will do this for free.

Comment: Thank you that does it. Is it something that can be made persistent so that I don't have to select every time?

Comment: @Angelo Mine appear to be persistent but, just in case anything changes, I'd be tempted to always use "more download options".

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a two-part question. [Richard has answered the first part](https://superuser.com/a/1811869/1850462), downloading/converting the photos already in HEIC.

The second part is about never getting photos in HEIC format. Sounds like you're using an iOS device. On iOS 17, go to Settings > Camera > Formats, and choose "Most Compatible". That will always use JPEG/H.264 formats, with limitations on fps for hi-res videos.

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207022

Answer (score 1):

If you've already downloaded them, you can convert them in Windows. Windows 10 and 11 supports HEIC/HEIF images if [HEIF Image Extensions](https://apps.microsoft.com/detail/9PMMSR1CGPWG?hl=en-us&gl=US), provided by Microsoft, is installed from the Windows Store. Once that's installed, HEIC will open in Windows Preview.

Once open, just hit the ... menu, Save As, and select JPEG format and re-save.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert HEIC to JPG/PNG on Widnows computer, actually there are many such tools online or offline. If you want to bacth convert HEIC images to JPG/PNG, try Coolmuster HEIC Converter. It's easy to use. You just need to add the HEIC images, set the output format, click the "Convert" button.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way on Windows 11 is to open each file in MS Paint and click “Save As” and select the desired format, JPEG, PNG, BMP, GIF and other formats option is available by default in MS Paint.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).